# Track 2 Details Sections Together for same item details

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a requirement where 3 tables are there

table 1 
[image: Header Table]

table 2
[image: Detail Table]

table 3

[image]

**and report format as following**

[image]

**Stored Procedures**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[BGradeWarehouseSummary]
@DOCNO int
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT        ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H.DOCNO, ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H.WAREHOUSENO, ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H.DOCDATE, ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H.ISCOPIED, ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H.CUSTOMERNO, 
                         ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H.CUSTOMERNAME, ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D.BATCHNO, ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D.PRODUCTCODE, ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D.PRODUCTDESC
FROM            ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H INNER JOIN
                         ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D ON ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H.DOCNO = ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D.DOCNO AND ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H.WAREHOUSENO = ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D.WAREHOUSENO
WHERE    ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_H.DOCNO = @DOCNO

END 

ALTER procedure [dbo].[WHS_BGradeWarehouseSummary]
@DOCNO int
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT        ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY.DOCNO,ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY.PRODUCTCODE, ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY.WAREHOUSENO, ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY.TOTALBATCHES, 
                         ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY.TOTALQTY
FROM            ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D INNER JOIN
                         ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY ON ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D.DOCNO = ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY.DOCNO AND 
                         ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D.PRODUCTCODE = ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY.PRODUCTCODE AND 
                         ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_D.WAREHOUSENO = ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY.WAREHOUSENO
WHERE    ADDON_P2_WHS_COUNTSO_WSUMMARY.DOCNO = @DOCNO

END  
GO
```

so I created 2 stored procedures and created main report and the sub report but unable to follow the same format in crystal report where detail section is getting duplicated, any suggestions to create the same format ?